# bash array using @ vs *, difference between the two

Tags: linux, bash

I cannot pinpoint the exact difference between using ${array[@]} vs ${array[*]}

What diff I see is when printing, but I guess there is more to it

```
declare -a array
array=("1" "2" "3")
IFS=","
printf "%s" ${array[@]}
printf "%s" ${array[*]}
IFS=" "
```

I searched on TLDP about it, but couldn't figure it out.
Is it a general bash thing or just for arrays?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should be: `printf "%s" "${array[*]}"` and `printf "%s" "${array[@]}"`

Comment: Ups, my bad, u are right. The question is still valid though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As mentioned in `man bash`:

> If the word is double-quoted, `${name[*]}` expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the `IFS` special variable, and `${name[@]}`
> expands each element of name to a separate word.

Examples:

```
array=("1" "2" "3")
printf "'%s'" "${array[*]}"
'1 2 3'
printf "'%s'" "${array[@]}"
'1''2''3'
```

Comment: So do they behave identically if the word is _not_ double-quoted?

Comment: @Jon Yes as said in the man page (the previous sentence mentioned in the post): _These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes._